# Listing items belonging to a logged-in user other item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to setup a website that offers services where each service has its own enquiry form. However, i want  the current user to see only the enquiries sent for a particular service he renders

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enquiries
  belongs_to :useractivity
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services
  has_many :enquiries
  belongs_to :useractivity
end



class Useractivity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :enquiries
end
```

I want to list on the users page all the enquiries made on his own services whenever he logs in

i have tried this query but it does seem to work

```
Enquiry.joins(:service, :useractivity).where("useractivity_user_id, @user.services")
```

Answer (score 0):

Associations are not much clear in question, still you can try this -

> All the enquiries made on his own services

```
Enquiry.joins(:service).where(services: {useractivity_id: @current_user.useractivity_id})
```

Comment: Thanks Gabba for the effort, this solution didn't work.

Comment: @Geni Could you please provide `Enquiry` model code snippet?

Comment: Thanks Gabba, I found my way around by using this code: "Enquiry.where(service_id: @user.services)". I'm so grateful